How to use factory for providing classes in nestjs dependency injection system?
I want to create multiple implementations of abstract service/class. And use certain one, according to some "settings". I have found this example in the official documentation.

Now I want to use something like this, but I have found that this is a pretty simple ternary operator, and I cannot use here any other injectable here(with useClass property).
Current working solution is to use "useFactory" property in next way:

But in this way I must instantiate these objects myself. For now it is easy(just to add parentheses). But when dependencies are added to these implementations, I would need to manage it myself, and I am not looking forward to such an opportunity.
For these reasons, I want to ask, what is the most common way to solve this issue? Maybe it is ok, only to use process.env in the ternary operator, or it ok to manage dependencies myself, of maybe there is something like "useClassFactory" property, where I can just use function, that returns class, that have been defined with "Injectable" decorator and then use it as plain injectable?

This can be achieved by injecting the ModuleRef which allows dependency injection class instantiation, e.g.:
@Module({
  providers: [
    {
      provide: 'SomeService',
      inject: [Settings, ModuleRef],
      useFactory: (settings: Settings, moduleRef: ModuleRef) => {
        return settings.useDb
          ? moduleRef.create(DbService)
          : moduleRef.create(MemoryService);
      },
    },
  ],
  exports: ['SomeService'],
})
export class SomeModule {}

If you're providing DbService and MemoryService in some already imported module, you can do:
        return settings.useDb
          ? moduleRef.get(DbService)
          : moduleRef.get(MemoryService);


In your situation, I think useClass is better & it's ok to use process.env in the tenary operator.
With useClass, you can still inject dependencies needed for UsersDbRepository & UsersInMemoryRepository by adding them to UsersModule's providers or adding modules that export those dependencies to UsersModule's imports

How should it changes in case more complex logic behind this?
